# connection has a remote Database

Tags: java, h2

I use H2 Database as DBMS from a remote computer,so I enabled remote access from a browser as follows:

```
webAllowOthers=true
```

but when i try to connect to the server from my java application i get this error from H2:

```
remote connections to this server are not allowed
```

screenshot:
[image]

And also already looking into the code Analyzer with (Error Code: 90117):

REMOTE_CONNECTION_NOT_ALLOWED = 90117

The error with code 90117 is thrown when trying to connect to a TCP server from another  machine, if remote connections are not allowed. To allow remote connections, start the TCP    server using the option -tcpAllowOthers as in:

*java org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpAllowOthers*

Or, when starting the server from an application, use:
*Server server = Server.createTcpServer("-tcpAllowOthers");
server.start();*

I do not understand how to activate the **tcpAllowOthers**, it does not exist in **.h2.server.properties** ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two different server:

- the Web Console server that is used to run the H2 Console tool (the GUI tool). It can be accessed by a browser only.
- the TCP server that allows to connect an application that uses JDBC, when using the client/server mode (`jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test`)

The file `.h2.server.properties` is only used for the Web Console server. It only supports `webAllowOthers=true`. This file is not used by the TCP server.

To enable remote access to the TCP server, you need to start the TCP server using the option  `-tcpAllowOthers`. To start both the Web Console server (the H2 Console tool) *and* the TCP server with remote connections enabled, you would need to use:

```
java -jar h2*.jar -web -webAllowOthers -tcp -tcpAllowOthers -browser
```

(this also starts a browser)

Comment: +1 for the quick response, the answer is already on the http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#console_settings  ,:-)