# H2 Console throwing a error webAllowOthers in H2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am using heruko to deploy my application when i am trying to load my h2 console using heruko it is throwing an error saying.

**H2 Console
Sorry, remote connections ('webAllowOthers') are disabled on this server.**

i am using the below settings  in my application.properties file

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:Roomy;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled = true 
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=true 
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
```

I done some google and added .h2.server.properties

```
#H2 Server Properties
1=Generic H2 (Memory)|org.h2.Driver|jdbc:h2:mem:Roomy;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE|sa
webAllowOthers=true
tcpAllowOthers=true
webPort=8082
webSSL=false
```

Please mention what i have done wrong and i am unable to view the h2 console could someone help on this.The cosole is working fine in the local and in the heroku the DB is working with no issues but unable to view the console .Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Thanks
Chaitanya

Comment: This question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838041/connection-has-a-remote-database

Comment: Hi Josh Thanks for the quick response but how i needto start my server using the command java -jar h2*.jar -web -webAllowOthers -tcp -tcpAllowOthers -browser .Do i need to add anything in the code or properties file

Comment: For Spring Application, have below entry in your application.properties spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true

Answer (score 71):

In `application.properties`, add following setting.

```
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
```

In my case, it works.

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine for me as well

Answer (score 19):

for those who use application.yml format

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      settings:
        web-allow-others: true
```

Answer (score 8):

Stop you project and add in your *application.properties*

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
```

Then run main and reload your browser.