# H2 console not working on Docker (remote connections ('webAllowOthers') are disabled)

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, h2

I have an api application which works on port 8080 with h2 db and h2-console is working good when I run the application from the IDE.

I have dockerized the project with dockerfile and docker-compose.yml, the project is working without problem, everything seems fine except that I cannot reach the h2-console when I run the project from docker.

Am getting the error: "*Sorry, remote connections ('webAllowOthers') are disabled on this server.*"

I checked some solutions and applied

```
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
```

to *application-DOCKER.properties* and also *application.properties* file but still cannot see the h2 console when I run the project on docker.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true` alone worked for me, can you share your Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem.
I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9838282/7044926) after researching this problem.

Before starting jar in the Dockerfile, you can make it start by giving the following arguments. ("-web -webAllowOthers -tcp -tcpAllowOthers -browser")

My Dockerfile;

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar", "-web -webAllowOthers -tcp -tcpAllowOthers -browser"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

In this way, I hope there will be no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to not have any spaces around comma:

```
Instead of : ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar", "-web -webAllowOthers -tcp -tcpAllowOthers -browser"]
```

For below worked:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar","-web -webAllowOthers -tcp -tcpAllowOthers -browser"]
```